# What causes a car to sometimes take awhile to start?

Tags: starting, dodge, journey

Okay let me explain.  I own a Dodge Journey 2009 and sometimes it will start right up fine.  Sometimes it will take a little while (maybe 4 or 5 seconds).  This happens in cold engine or warm.  So I put the key in to start it and it will do this "da da da da da da da da da da da vroom" and sometimes as I said that will last 4 or 5 seconds, and sometimes it starts right away. It's been doing this to me for about three years.  If the starter is bad, would it have lasted three years like this?

I have brand new spark plugs, brand new fuel pump, brand new fuel injectors, brand new battery, and by brand new I mean within the last three months.

Comment: I cannot tell you what it is, offhand, but I can tell you *it's not the starter*. If the problem were with the starter, you would get nothing (or possibly slow turning of the engine). That the starter will routinely make the engine go round, pretty much rules it out as well as the battery.

Comment: Bad check valve at fuel pump?  Does the car ALWAYS start reliably if you turn the key to on, wait five full seconds before turning the key to start?

Comment: @zipzit I haven't tried that, but as the OP stated, I have a brand new fuel pump, wouldn't the check valve be part of that?  The dealership changed it out on me.

Comment: Not sure on that vehicle how they manage that.  It could be part of the pump, or part of the rest of the fuel delivery module assembly.  There could also be a leak in the fuel delivery module (inside the tank) that lets fuel leak back into the tank after vehicle shut off.)  Its an easy test.  let car sit for 24 hours, try key start immediately;  if fail, then try to do the five second wait test.

Comment: @Travis Sound like air in the fuel system. Had this Nissan D-22, If I didn't drive it for a couple of days It'd take longer to fire the truck up, sometimes It'd start for a minute and then It'd just die, then I'd use the manual pump to prime it and of we went. But If I drove within a couple of hours there would be no problem. Sent it to a Diesel Specialist and he came up with a "sketchy turbotimer" I didn't take it so I changed two diesel filters out of 4(3+1 percolator) when I noticed that the flexible part of the fuel line had a slit that would puke diesel out when the truck was off.

Comment: Sounds like [vanilla ice cream vapor lock](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/cone-of-silence/) to me.

Answer (score 0):

During a startup, the engine computer is looking for camshaft and crankshaft sensor readings (among other things). If it can't sync those up right away, it will keep trying until it gets a signal or it will default to using readings from just the crank or camshaft(s).

I would go to Autozone or equivalent and have them scan your car for DTCs. If there are any codes related to sensors, then I would consider checking the wiring to the sensors or even replacing them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a fuel "pressure" problem too me. If you haven't changed your in-line filter I would do that sooner than later. They are generally inexpensive and easy to do. This was the case on my 1998 Pontiac Fire Bird.